# Late 70-mid 80s kids’ music album?

Tags: romans, music

When I was a kid, I had a cassette by I think a pair of male artists, probably accompanied by acoustic guitar? One of the tracks included these lyrics:

"Be not conformed to this world, but be transformed into his world by the renewing, by the renewing of your mind."

I think there might’ve been a bee on the tape cover or maybe one of the guys just accentuated the word “beeee” in the song. I can’t recall any of the other tracks. I’ve searched Safari, Duck Duck Go, YouTube, and Spotify and haven’t found it.

Does anyone else remember the artists’ names, the album title, anything like that?